# Changing username for git in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode5

Our git repository is accessed at ssh://git@server/.../.../project.git.  Each of us on the team created our own private key and emailed those to the git administrator.

My problem is in Xcode, since the "git" username is part of the URI, it assumes that's the username I want to use and disables the username field in preferences from changing.  When using other tools, the pushes from Xcode show user git with my right username, but I would like it to use my username instead of the git username.

I don't understand git well enough to be able to ask my administrator the right questions.  Is this something I need help with from him, or is there some defaults file I can change in Xcode to use the username I want?

Comment: Did you have a success fixing that? Xcode 13 still has the same issue as you described. User Name is "git" and disabled for editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it directly using GIT using terminal command:

```
git remote set-url origin NEW_URL
```

If you want to change username do:

```
git config --global user.name "newUsername"
```

Comment: I don't want to change the URL.  I want Xcode to use the user.name property that I see when I run the command "git config -l", and not the username from the URL.  This works in Eclipse when I do Android development but not from Xcode when I do iOS development.

Comment: Than use git config --global user.name "newUsername"

Comment: The user.name is set to my name.  My guess is that Xcode is not using that value

Answer (score -1):

You can change the default username for your repository's url by updating the remote url of your git project. You can do so with the following terminal command:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://username@server.com/path/to/project.git
```

1. `username` is your username of choice that is different from the default `git` username
2. `server.com/path/to/project.git` is the remote server path to your git project